# Python .format - error

Tags: python, format

I'm trying to get the following to work in a Python interpreter, however it gives me an error and I cannot seem to find where my mistake is?  (I'm a python newbie)

```
>>> print 'THe value of PI is approx {}.'.format(math.pi)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What python version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use Python version < 2.6, version >= 2.6 support {0}, version >= 2.7 support {} format.

Comment: This is also supported Python 2.7

What’s New in Python 2.7 — Python v2.7 documentation
http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes

Answer (score 1):

You're using a too old version of python that does not support this string formatting method. On Python 2.6 this is the result (with a small correction):

```
>>> print 'THe value of PI is approx {0}.'.format(math.pi)
THe value of PI is approx 3.14159265359.
```

This method is the new way of string formatting ([PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)) and is supposed to replace the old way (with the %). I'm still used to the old way but in the long run I'll probably switch to the new way.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
>>> print "The value of PI is approx {'%s'}." % format(math.pi)
The value of PI is approx {'3.14159265359'}.
```

So does this:

```
>>> print "The value of PI is approx '%f'"  % math.pi
The value of PI is approx '3.141593'
```

Comment: OP is asking about advanced string formatting, not the % interpolation.

Comment: OP is asking as a Python noob about a formatting error, which I've corrected.  I'm using Python 2.6.  Where's your answer, Wai Yip Tung?  What have you offered that's better?

Comment: Just because someone hasn't posted an answer of their own doesn't mean they can't point out issues with others' answers.

Comment: That's true; I just disagree with the "issue".  Where do you see anything about "advanced string formatting" in the original question?  I see someone who was a noob looking for an explanation for a simple error.